# How can I connect to jdbc as a streaming source in Databricks

Tags: scala, jdbc, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, aws-databricks

Using the example from https://github.com/sutugin/spark-streaming-jdbc-source
I've attempted to connect to a Postgres database as a streaming source in AWS Databricks.

I have a cluster running:
11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12)

This library is installed on my cluster:
org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.12:3.3.2

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
.builder
.appName("StructuredJDBC")
.getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val jdbcOptions = Map(
"user" -> "myusername",
"password" -> "mypassword",
"database" -> "testDB",
"driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
"url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://dbhostname:5432:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false"
)

// Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from jdbc
val stream = spark.readStream
.format("jdbc-streaming")
.options(jdbcOptions + ("dbtable" -> "dimensions_test_table") + ("offsetColumn" -> "loaded_timestamp"))
.load

// Start running the query that prints 'select result' to the console
val query = stream.writeStream
.outputMode("append")
.format("console")
.start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

But I'm plagued with the error:
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/StreamWriteSupport
Caused by: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.StreamWriteSupport

The only info I can find on this error doesn't appear to apply to my situation.
What am I missing?

I've looked for other libraries, but this appears to be the only one that supports jdbc as a source on Scala 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems here:

- You don't need to install the `org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.12:3.3.2` library on Databricks cluster. Databricks runtime includes all necessary Spark libraries, and by installing the open source version you most probably will break Databricks-specific modifications.
- To use this library you need to compile it yourself and install onto the cluster. But as I see, it wasn't updated for 4 years, and by default it's compiled for Spark 3.0 (that matches to DBR 7.3).

If you want to get changes from database, you may look onto Change Data Capture functionality, like, [CDC for RDS MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/enable-change-data-capture-on-amazon-rds-for-mysql-applications-that-are-using-xa-transactions/).  Then data could be landed to S3, and picked up for example, with [Delta Live Tables implementing CDC pattern](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-cdc.html).